# Create wallet address on user registration for trading platform

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, ripple, ethereum

I am creating a crypto-trading platform . I wanted to know how to create wallet address dynamically for all new registered user and also create new address for every transaction.

I am using bitcoind for bitcoin and will be doing RPC calls directly. Also let me know if there is any better way to do it.

Comment: Are you asking for an implementation or is it a theoretical question? Also will your application have access to the keys?

Comment: We'll need more information to specifically answer your question: what Bitcoin node software are you using? Are you connecting through a client library, straight RPC calls, or just using the command line?

Comment: @Motoma I am using bitcoind and will be doing direct RPC calls for now. Let know if there are any other better options.

Comment: @JBaczuk I am asking for implementation , yes application will have have access to keys.

Comment: since i have worked on exchange platform and payment gateways you can message me in persion about the doubts, i will be happy to help you

Comment: creating wallet address dynamically can be done with RPCs but for a exchange you wiil be needing extra services like mempool crawler, block crawler and soo on

Answer (score 0):

The call you want is `getnewaddress`, which will generate a new Bitcoin address, add it to the current wallet, and return the address as the result of the call.

You can find documentation for the call here: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/wallet/getnewaddress/

If you were writing this in Python, it would look something like this:

```
from pyjsonrpc import ServiceProxy

bitcoin = ServiceProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8332")
bitcoin.username = 'testuser'
bitcoin.password = 'testpass'
print(bitcoin.getnewaddress())
```

You would then need to track the addresses generated and record them with your user accounts, monitoring transactions and crediting users as they come in.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I will try this approach and update my result here.